# Styling Directions from GoogleMaps V3

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google maps API V3 one can generate directions. I am trying to style these directions more than just changing the colour and font size. I want it to look more like our site.

The API seams to output a table with a series of style information. I would like to be able to style this properly. Is there a way of outputting the data in a different manner than the standard table?

Answer (score 0):

The Directions API documentation indicates that you can retrieve the data as JSON or XML which would seem to make it possible to output the data in pretty much any manner you want.  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponses

The only restrictions appear to be:  "Note: the Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited. Additionally, calculation of directions generates copyrights and warnings which must be displayed to the user in some fashion. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12)."